# Can I use java-grpc as a library instead of a framework?

Tags: java, json, grpc, grpc-java

I am a big believer in composition over inheritance as well as libraries over frameworks (which is extremely similar to composition since libraries are composed).  This code here from the gRPC java example is telling me to some degree that java-grpc is a framework in addition to being just a library(which is fine, nothing wrong with that)...

```
    Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(port)
            .addService(new GreeterImpl())
            .build()
            .start();
```

I am trying to have my webserver(webpieces) receive requests on these urls

- https://host/grpc -> webpieces would just re-use the grpc library(hopefully) for encoding/decoding
- https://host/json/{grpcMethod} -> webpieces would grab the grpcMethod and decode the json into the grpc object to call the service here

(edit for more clarity based on first answer)...

**Key Point -> Json should come in AND use the same protobuf objects.  I should not have to create json pojo as seen in this json grpc blow post [JSON grpc](https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-with-json/)**

I really need a java-gRPC api that I can interact with such that I can ask the library to encode/decode in both directions.  This then gives customers the option to do gRPC on our public API or use JSON if they prefer.

I am starting to think with java-grpc, this is not possible since it's a framework rather than just a library(I mean it's a library of course too but since I have to plugin to it rather than use it, it is also a framework).

I did spend a good amount of time today starting to create a new io.grpc.ServerProvider and a new io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider but wow, there is way way more to implement than I would have suspected for simply encode/decode these objects for me which is what I was looking for.

One last question too since gRPC is over http/2.  I don't see a location in client or server in java-grpc to supply the url path that should be hit?

webpieces actually supports streaming in both directions like gRPC up to a point(the http frontend 100% supports it).  We have some work to do to drive it down into the controllers which we will do at some point(at which point, we can server web pages, gRPC, and JSON all on the same serverless server we have setup).

BONUS POINTS: Webpieces like the old 'java' playframework ALSO supports hot compile when developing so it would be VERY IDEAL if we can have the gRPC server under webpieces instead of the gRPC server being on top killing off the no-restart development we have going on.

thanks for any tips there!
Dean

Answer (score 1):

I still think gRPC is more like a library.

Anyways, [the JSON blog post](https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-with-json/) will give you a good idea how to serialize and deserialize request/responses. Also, it shows you how to manually provide MethodDescriptors and ServerServiceDefinitions for defining method and service including the routing.

Protobuf is the default serialization for gRPC. So, using protobuf is much easier. You don't normally need to worry about those low level APIs. Nonetheless, in the core, it is not strongly depends on specific serialization as you can see from the blog post.

Comment: I was actually reading through that earlier myself.  I am trying to figure out though how to use the same protobuf generated entities so that I can do both json and grpc to the same code with the protobuf entities being fed to the service rather than these gson entities.

Comment: I really appreciate the help!  The one sticking point I had in that article is that it doesn't address this statement in my post "webpieces would grab the grpcMethod and decode the json into the grpc object to call the service here".  Instead, that article requires me to create 'beans' that can go back and forth to json.  I really want to use 'one' entity for each bean for gRPC protobuf communication and json communication.

Comment: oh, and upvote for being close though!  Perhaps what I am trying to do is not feasible yet or at least not easily without doing a bunch of reflection, etc. etc. which I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: do you have a twitter handle I can follow?    you have been a great help so far.  Hopefully I can get to a hot compile/no restart gRPC server instead of the ones that exist.  We like to create java rapid development platforms with no server restarts.

Comment: glad that it is helpful, but i don't do twitter. hot reloading sounds very interesting. i am not sure how you can do it fast. iirc, protoc doesn't support incremental compile. if you are only considering webpieces, it might be feasible

Comment: yup, got it all working in the plugin.  I use the eclipse compiler and the protobuf generates new source and webpieces picks up the changes on the source now.  The plugin for grpc-json is complete.  I generate endpoints of /{yourchoice}/{grpcService}/{grpcMethod}.  now to see if I can get the binary working.  https://github.com/deanhiller/webpieces/blob/master/webserver-plugins/plugin-grpc-json/